# Which IC with top mark 15ZL is shown in this image?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Can anyone determine the part number of this IC with top mark 15ZL and find the datasheet?

[image: Photo of IC with top mark 15ZL]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a Torex [XC6201P302MR](https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xc6201/XC6201.pdf) 3.0V LDO regulator.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Ali - Hi, Your comment suggests that you have received as much help as you need. In order to mark the topic as solved, please consider ["accepting" the answer which most helped you](/help/someone-answers) (i.e. click the "tick mark" next to that answer, to turn it green). Although accepting an answer isn't mandatory, it is *strongly encouraged* as your question is then shown as having an accepted answer in various lists, it makes it clear that you aren't waiting for more answers, and we don't get nagged for it being a question without an accepted answer. Thanks!